# PDFSharp - Report Document Colors and Transparency

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, pdfsharp

I am having some problems with the PDF files that I make using the PDFSharp library. The files are ok as long as I am viewing them normally.

However I need these files to be changed using the accessibility options (Edit -> Preferences -> Accessibility (in the left menu Categories) -> Report Document Colors -> Custom Color). Whenever there is image with transperancy and/or transparent masks and the Background color is set to black everything disappears.

I looked at the PDFSharp code and it seems that they are setting some transparent SMask, which I did not find to do anything noticeable (at least for me), but I am not sure if I disable it will it screw up something that I cannot think of.

Most probably I won't get help on this one, but I hope that someone knows something more about this problem with PDF Transparency and the Accessibility options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transparency mask is created for images with transparency only.

So if your images contain black lines and a transparent background and you change the color of PDF pages to black, you will see black lines on a black background - you will see nothing.

If your images contain black lines on a white background, you will see your image as you know it: black lines on a white background.

Transparency is a feature, it's optional.

Maybe there's a bug in PDFsharp. If I watch the output of the Graphics sample with black background color, pages 4 and 5 are completely black (looks wrong to me).
The output of the Hello MigraDoc sample looks correct to me. The image on page 1 does not use transparency and keeps it white background, the chart on page 6 is transparent (which leads to black lines on a black background).
But maybe that's a bug in Adobe Reader - everything looks fine if I do not set a background color, but activate the transparency grid instead.

If you think that your images do not contain transparency, then we'll need files (PDF and image) for further examination.

Edit: I just checked the output of the Graphics sample with Adobe Acrobat 5 - all pages display correctly even with black background color. With Adobe Acrobat 8 and Adobe Reader X pages 4 and 5 are black. Looks like a bug in Adobe Acrobat/Reader to me.

Comment: Thank you very much. I suspected that it is something related to PDF and the readers because I saw similar problem elsewhere too. Also I figured out the use of the soft mask and how exactly things are going to be screwed up :).